# Scaling an animation

Tags: animation, transforms

I'd like to scale down some selected range of frames in `Blender` (v 2.79). I've just select frames range in the `Dope Sheet` using the `b` key and then scaled down selection (from 1.0 to 0.5) using the `s` key. Unfortunately after the operation the animations "get broken" - the scaled keyframes lost their animation - the object does NOT animate when i run over the scaled frames.
How can I scale the frames range NOT to lose the animation? Is there a way to "merge" this scaled frames with the rest of animation?.
Thx for help.

PS.
I'm attaching the image of problem:[image]

Comment: Did you select **all** required keyframes. (e.g. You selected all pose bones in pose mode) *before* scaling?

Comment: @Leander I don't know what You mean "all required keyframes" There is NO bones in the animation - I's just key-frame animation because  it was imported  from the md2 Quake file.

Comment: In this case I meant objects. 3DBear's answer describes what I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing some keys in the selection.

1. Make sure the animation track (action) you want to change is selected and isn't locked in NLA window.
2. Go to the graph editor.
3. Make sure that the search bar in the left corner is empty.
4. Select all the objects (or bones) that keys you want to stretch.
5. With your cursor placed in the graph editor press (Alt H) - unhide all the channels that could have been hidden during the working process.
6. Then press A to select all the keys in the graph editor and press the "Home" button to frame all selected.
7. Now you should see all your keyframes in front of you. To scale the part safely I suggest to key all selected objects in the first and the last frame of your selected area (so if you are stretching the area from 10-th to 50-th frame, then go to frame 10, press I in your viewport. Choose Location&Rotation. Then go to frame 50 and repeat the same action). In this case your animation will be stretched evenly.

Finally, you can safely select the area that you chose to scale down, and by pressing S and then X you'll be able to scale the speed up or down.

Following these steps, you'll be sure you haven't lost some channels due to locks, filters or missing frames.